# data frame splitting based on specific conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a data frame having 1200 records and 30 variables.
I want to divide data frame into six sample with each sample size of 200.
So far I tried with following R code:

```
createSample<-function(df)
{
 totalSample<-ceiling((nrow(df)/200))
 sampleSize=200
  for(i in 1:totalSample)
   {
        ## user should have to define file name and start & end row
        file <-'demo.csv'
        start <- (i-1)*sampleSize
        end <- (i*sampleSize)
        function1(file,start,end)    ## this will call to another function then again control reaches here
        }
     }
createSample(rawData) ## function call
```

Above code result with unbound error, because I can’t access first records with 0 index value, but instead in R we can access first records with index value 1.

```
  My expectation is:
  In the first iteration of for loop I want access 1-200 records.
  In the next iteration I want to access 201-400 records. Till total six   time repetition, because for loop will execute for total of six times.

 so by reading the data frame i want my start and end value should be dynamically change in each iteration..
  for example: in first iteration
   start<-1
   end<-200
   in second iteration:
   start<-201
   end<-400   and so on...
 Thanks in advance….
```

Comment: reproducible example?

Comment: Why not split(data, sample(rep(1:6,200)))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we don't know about the second function mentioned in the OP's post, we can skip about that part and instead split the dataset into a `list` of `data.frame`s that have each n rows (i.e. 200.  The last `list` element would have the remaining rows if the `nrow` of the dataset is not a multiple of n).

```
createSample <- function(df, n, Sample=FALSE){
   SeqN <- seq_len(nrow(df))
   g1 <- (SeqN-1)%/%n +1
   Start <- unname(tapply(SeqN, g1, head, 1))
   End <- unname(tapply(SeqN, g1, tail, 1))
   if(Sample){
   g1 <- sample(g1)
   }
   list(Splitdat=lapply(split(SeqN, g1), function(i) df[i,]),
        Start=Start,
        End=End)
 }

createSample(yourdat, 200)
createSample(yourdat, 200, TRUE)
```

NOTE: Added an option to randomly `sample` the observations in the function.

Comment: this works ...but if the division of data frame is not equal with sample records at last i m not able to convert into data frame..suppose if a last list having only 150 records instead of 200.

Comment: @andy In that case it will return the last 150 instead of 200.  What do you want to return if that is the case?  Each `list` element is a `data.frame`.  So, I am not sure what you meant by `not able to convert into data frame`

Comment: i edited the question. can u help now..i just want updated value of start and end variable in each iteration..

Comment: @andy Wouldn't the values will be 1, 200, 201, 400, etc?

Comment: yes it is... but it gives me 6 list of 200 records..i am hitting some API and that API will select 200 records from data frame, based on start and end values...that's why i need start and end updated value in each iteration..

Comment: @andy If you need the rownames of the first and last row of each `list` that can be done.